# How to remove html content from another html content

Tags: jquery, html, performance

I have following html.

```
<dl class="item-options">
            <dd class="truncated" style="color:red;">DSOX3000-232, RS232/UART Serial Decode and Trigger - in <a onclick="return false" class="dots" href="#">...</a>/<div class="truncated_full_value"><dl class="item-options"><dt>Software Applications</dt><dd id="pppp">DSOX3000-232, RS232/UART Serial Decode and Trigger - installed, DSOX3000-AMS, CAN and LIN Automotive Serial Decode - installed, DSOX3000-MAT, Advanced Math Analysis for Infiniivision Oscilloscopes - installed, DSOX3000-VID, Enhanced Video/TV Application Package - installed/</dd></dl></div>
            </dd>          

            <div class="mdata">
                <dd class="truncated">DSOX3000-001, WaveGen 20 MHz Function/Arbitrary Wavefor <a onclick="return false" class="dots" href="#">...</a>/<div class="truncated_full_value"><dl class="item-options"><dt>Advanced Analysis</dt><dd id="pppp">DSOX3000-001, WaveGen 20 MHz Function/Arbitrary Waveform Generator - installed/</dd></dl></div></dd>
            </div>          


            <p id="warranty" style="margin-top:10px"></p>
                <dd>R-51B-001-5F, Return to Agilent Warranty - 5 years</dd><p>
            </p>              
 </dl>
```

I have all content under `<dl class="item-options">` in one variable suppose  `var mycontent`.

How to remove this content `<p id="warranty" style="margin-top:10px"></p><dd>R-51B-001-5F, Return to Agilent Warranty - 5 years</dd><p></p>` 
from that variable `mycontent`.

`mycontent`
is a variable which will be passed to a popup.So I want to retain

```
<p id="warranty" style="margin-top:10px"></p><dd>R-51B-001-5F, Return to Agilent Warranty - 5 years</dd><p></p>
```

In html document but to remove from variable only.

Thanks

Comment: $( "#warranty" ).remove();

Comment: You can clone it to avoid messing with the original element. See my answer for further explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the content of warranty

tag from `mycontent` variable like following.

```
<p id="warranty" style="margin-top:10px"></p>
     <dd>R-51B-001-5F, Return to Agilent Warranty - 5 years</dd><p>
</p>
```

var warranty=jQuery('#warranty').next().html();

mycontent.=mycontent.replace(warranty,'');

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(mycontent).find("#warranty").remove();
```

**OR**

```
$(".item-options").find("#warranty").remove();
```

**EDIT:**

One way to do that is to **clone()** *mycontent* and put it in a new variable. You'll be able to retain the original *mycontent* and play around with its clone without affecting the original element.

```
var mycontentForPopup = $(mycontent).clone().find("#warranty").remove();
```

And then, use *mycontentForPopup* for your popup. Send me some feedback if this didnt work..

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to select the nodes you want to remove and .remove() them. Assume `mycontent` is a jQuery reference to the node with class `item-options`:

```
var warranty = mycontent.children('#warranty');
var txtContent = warranty.siblings('dd').last();
warranty.remove();
txtContent.remove();
```

If `mycontent` is a `DOM` node then just select it with `jQuery`:

```
var $mycontent = $(mycontent);
```

A suggestion would be to structure your `DOM` such that the `warranty` element holds nodes related to it as `children` not as `siblings`. Otherwise the semantics is lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
$("#warranty", $(mycontent)).remove();
```

But I think the code is wrong:

```
<p id="warranty" style="margin-top:10px"></p>
    <dd>R-51B-001-5F, Return to Agilent Warranty - 5 years</dd><p>
</p>
```

or:

```
<p id="warranty" style="margin-top:10px">
    <dd>R-51B-001-5F, Return to Agilent Warranty - 5 years</dd>
</p>
```